# Converting to PDO with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert an SQL statement to PDO.

I cant seem to figure this out.

Here is the sql statement.

```
 <h3>Recent Post</h3>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    $category = $row['category']; 
    ?>
    <div class="features">
        <div class="box"><img src="Developer/common-files/icons/time@2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">       
             <h6><?php echo $category; ?> - <?php echo $title; ?></h6>
             <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>  
</div>
```

From what I have read I was under the impression that this would work

PDO statement

```
 <h3>Recent Post</h3>
     <?php
        $stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        }
     ?>
    <div class="features">
        <div class="box"><img src="Developer/common-files/icons/time@2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Wuno Inc.">       
             <h6><?php echo $row['category']; ?> - <?php echo $row['title']; ?></h6>
             <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

On my page I do not get any error but no information populates.

Comment: Your code has already executed the while loop before you `echo $row`, so nothing will show up becuase `$row` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ending your `while` statement immediately with a stray closing bracket `}`.  Move the bracket below your output, like you have in your first code example.

Also, don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any data used in the context of HTML, to ensure you generate valid HTML and prevent injection of scripts and what not.

Comment: TY for answering so quick. I am a goof ball and I edited the question. long story short. I have it posting its just showing one post. I need it to show all of the post from the data base. I do this with a for each right? how can I add this?

Comment: @NichoDiaz No, you don't need a `foreach`.  What you have will work just fine if you just move the closing bracket...

Comment: OK thanks a ton man. Ill accept as soon as it will let me. I feel so dumb right now haha.

Comment: @NichoDiaz Ha, no need to feel dumb... you posted a good question.